# Bootstrap columns overlapping on small screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I made two columns, one for title and the other one for projects, which I made scrollable.
It works as I want on desktop view, but when I shrink the viewport to mobile screen and try to scroll through the projects, they start overlapping the title. Here's the link for the problem: [text](https://fatimakay.github.io/#/projects). Try to scroll with the viewport shrunk to 500 width.

I tried playing with the height of the projects column but it still does it. If you need the code let me know I'll add that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the parent container of those columns `row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2` classes. Starting with medium width and going up (lg, xl), you made it to be two columns. For xs and sm width, it uses `row-cols-1` which makes it single column. Remove `row-cols-1` class and you will get two columns in all sizes.